# WAN on router's client device

Tags: linux, networking, router, openwrt

I have:

- **OpenWRT router** with one Ethernet WAN port, two Gbps LAN ports (one connected to a dumb 8-port Ethernet switch) and WiFi 5GHz onboard, yet no USB port.
- Arch Linux ARM powered Pine64 **ROCK64** SBC in the LAN, working 24/7 as a multi-purpose server, having one Gbps LAN port (connected to the router) and multiple USB 2/3 ports.
- **USB LTE modem**

I need to set up the modem on the ROCK64 device to act as a WAN interface / gateway, with the OpenWRT router still doing routing, DHCP, WLAN etc. (probably still having its Ethernet WAN interface up and having MWAN on both WAN interfaces, but this is an option).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: So you want the internet connection to go from the USB LTE modem, to the Arch ROCK64 box, then out it's ethernet port into the OpenWRT router, and from there to WiFi & it's other two LAN ports? Sure, that should work... assuming you can get the USB LTE modem working with the Arch box. Sharing the connection from there over ethernet should be the easiest part (was literally one setting in the GUI for MX-Linux)

Comment: @Xen2050 I need to understand the concept of having external WAN(s) on another device(s) within the LAN rather than using the router's native one (as it lacks the proper extension ports) and how to set up the router. The actual WAN device is irrelevant (it might be the mentioned USB LTE modem, an mSATA LTE+ modem, a GPON access point... whatever). Should I set up a static route on the router with the default gateway on another LAN IP? Or anything else? Please elaborate if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before using a bluetooth USB adapter sharing an internet connection from a phone, getting the bluetooth connection working was by far the hardest part (luckily that's not part of this question).

I didn't have to manually set (or even look at) any routes or iptables or anything like that.

Anyway, I connected an ethernet cable from the linux computer (ROCK64 in your case) to the WAN port of a plain old router (set to receive a DHCP WAN/Internet connection).

After getting a working internet connection through the USB device to the linux computer, I used the `network-manager` via it's gui `network-manager-gnome` "NetworkManager Applet" to edit the automatically created ethernet connection listing. The key setting is in the IPv4 Settings tab, changing the top option "Method" to "Shared to other computers". Then (first disconnecting the ethernet connection if it was connected) connecting to the new / edited shared ethernet connection.

[image]

There's also a setting in the General tab called "Metered connection" that if set to yes *might possibly* help use less data.

And that was all. The router receives an IP address through DHCP from the linux machine, and the linux machine should automatically route any packets from the router to the internet via the USB device.

The router, and anything else connected to it, will see the linux computer as part of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to connect the USB modem to the Arch Linux box and have
it create a wireless hotspot.

To have the modem as the DHCP monitor, you will have to configure
the wireless hotspot as bridged, for the wireless clients to access
the same network interface and subnet.

The performance of this configuration won't be the same as using a
wireless modem, but it should work.

For detailed advice see :

- [Arch Linux - Software access point](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/software_access_point)
- [REDIT - Wifi Hotspot](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/cqdocn/wifi_hotspot/)

Comment: You didn’t mention that in your question